# Spark, path to the input file

Tags: input, apache-spark

I have a master on the local PC and use two servers as workers. When I start Spark program, first of all I have to import my input file. For the correct input (currently) I should have my input file on the hard disk of master and both workers (path has to be the same). It means the same data-set should be placed on three different places. How I can avoid this and store my data set on the unique place, without to get input error?

Comment: Use distributed file system?

Comment: Put your file on hdfs and then load from there in spark-job.

Comment: @zero323, Mahendra, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

In order to do so, you need to use a Distributed File System such as HDFS (Hadoop). Two examples of reading a file are the following:

`tweets = sc.textFile("hdfs://scraper.ccs.neu.edu/user/cbw/a1_tweets.txt") # load data from HDFS`

`words = sc.textFile("hdfs://scraper.ccs.neu.edu/user/cbw/words*.txt") # load data from HDFS`

The first one is a conventional file reading, while the second one has a * which will cause to read multiple files (just like wholeTextFiles).

Note that when you reference files in HDFS, you must specify a fully qualified URL that includes the hostname (e.g. **scraper** ).

Data in HDFS are stored in blocks and are stored in all datanodes. Metadata about this file system is stored on Namenode. So you will have the data spread in different nodes, and hadoop takes cares of when and how to send blocks between nodes.

Comment: If HDFS and HADOOP_HOME are set correctly when running spark, you *don't* need the fully qualified URL as HDFS will be the default FS.

Answer (score 1):

General point is to have file system that is visible from all of the worker nodes.

Spark can interface with a wide variety, including Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS),MapR File System (MapR-FS),Cassandra,OpenStack Swift, Amazon S3, Kudu (taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Spark)).

Local file system is one of the options like you mentioned - several copies on all of the workers. One more case to use "local" file system is to mount network drives or use something like NAS or SAN.

All of these approaches require just different URIs to the input file, but all end up with simple call

```
sc.textFile("protocol://path/to/a/file");
```